# How to create document in couchbase from cbq

Tags: couchbase

I have successfully created my bucket and want to insert the document.
Lets suppose I have to insert the data in JSON format like this:

```
{
    "name": "abc",
    "password": "abcd123",
    "user_id": "abc123"
}
```

And I want to insert into my bucket.

Please help thanks in advance.

Comment: And if you have a large volume of docs like this to insert into Couchbase, you might want to look at cbdocloader in the bin directory. If that is not what you are after, then disregard this of course.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the INSERT statement (available starting couchbase 4.1): http://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/4.1/n1ql/n1ql-language-reference/insert.html

```
INSERT INTO yourBucketName (KEY, VALUE) VALUES ("keyOfYourObject", 
  { "name": "abc", "password": "abcd123", "user_id": "abc123"}) RETURNING * ;
```